# Are there any websites that offer browsing through the repository of published wikileaks?

Tags: webapp-rec

I expect the answer to this question may change rapidly, as Julian Assange and his site are "under attack" and people are working hard to make the leaked information more accessible...

**Edit:**

I'm specifically looking for a site where I can *browse* the repository. I'm aware that the wikileaks site is currently accessible and the documents that live there are available for download. However, I want a site where I can read leaked documents without having to download all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The [official site](http://www.wikileaks.ch/) is up right now, and the [mirrors page](http://www.wikileaks.ch/mirrors.html) currently lists **1697** mirror sites.

If wikileaks.ch is not accessible, try e.g. some of these:

- http://wikileaks.info/
- http://www.wikileaks.de/
- http://www.wikileaks.nl/
- http://www.wikileaks.at/

The repository of recently leaked embassy cables is at [/cablegate.html](http://www.wikileaks.de/cablegate.html).

Even if none of the DNS aliases / mirror websites worked, the leaked cablegate data (as well as earlier leaks) are surely also available through P2P networks such as BitTorrent.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited my question to clarify what I mean by "browse."

Comment: @Ami, I'm not sure what you mean, because at the Wikileaks site (and mirrors) you **can** [browse the documents](http://www.wikileaks.de/cablegate.html) without having to download all of them. (You can browse the cables by release (leak) date, creation date, origin (which embassy), and confidentiality classification, for example.) Or are you specifically talking about earlier, pre-cablegate leaks?

Comment: you're right. I didn't realize that.